# Extract rows from matrix in R

Tags: r, vector

I just start using `R`, and I want to extract the rows from the `matrix` (input) to calculate the `mean` and `sum` of each row.
I can't use `rowMeans(X)` because I have some missing data.  How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe then `rowMeans(X, na.rm=TRUE)` where the second argument removes missing values. For subsetting, see examples in `?"["` and the [intro to R manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `rowMeans(X, na.rm=TRUE)`